# Is there any way to detect that cocos2d::ui::ScrollView stopped scrolling?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android

I can't find a way to detect scroll ending in `cocos2d::ui::ScrollView`. Does anyone knows how can I detect it?

Comment: for UIScrollView, scrollViewDidEndDecelerating helps to find end of scroll

Answer (score 1):

Add this line and try to run may be its work

```
scrollView->setBounceEnabled(true );
```

or

```
scrollView->setTouchEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is help for you.using cocos2d v3.8.1

> http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/uploads/default/11533/88a6e9c35c275361.zip